# Telegram bot .hears()-method with multiple triggers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am developing a telegram chat bot with node.js and telegraf.

Is there a way to use multiple triggers with the bot.hears method for telegram bots, like for if statements when you use ||?
I want that if the user types menu, a menu appears and when the user types back, the same menu also appears.

Right now I have to write the same method twice, like this:

```
bot.hears('Menu', ctx =>
    {
        ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'These are our products.',
                {
                     //show menu
                })

    })

bot.hears('Back', ctx =>
    {
        ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'These are our products.',
                {
                     //show menu
                })

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`.hears()` documentation](https://telegraf.js.org/v3#/?id=hears);

> [image]

You can use a [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a Trigger;

For example, a regex like [`/Menu|Back/`](https://regex101.com/r/3eu1yf/1/) will trigger for both `/Menu` as `/Back`.

---

One of the [examples](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/2bb7e62533adf89729fadcde411e82e075580e8f/docs/examples/example-bot.ts) uses this method. Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/2bb7e62533adf89729fadcde411e82e075580e8f/docs/examples/example-bot.ts) to get a general idea on the implementation.