# Telegram Bot API Telegraf: how to register command wildcard

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf

I am using the NodeJS Telegraf library to implement a Telegram Bot. Everything works fine, except that ultimately, I need a lot of different Telegram commands (such as "/abc", "/def", ..., hundreds in the end) for the user of the bot.

I only found ways to register individual commands via their names with the Telegraf middleware. Example:

```
bot.command(['undo'], (ctx) => undo(ctx))
```

Is there a way to register command wildcards (thru eg a regular expression) with the middleware? Ideally something like the following, which actually does **not** work with the current Telegraf API:

```
bot.command(/x.*/, (ctx) => do_something_with(ctx))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've managed to solve it since then, but I have also been looking for an answer to this, and came across this thread: [Telegram bot .hears()-method with multiple triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66264318/telegram-bot-hears-method-with-multiple-triggers)

`.hears()` is able to take in regular expressions, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben Jacob Lee is right. **hears** is the way:

```
bot.hears(/\/(.+)/, (ctx) => {
  const cmd = ctx.match[1];
  switch (cmd) {
    case 'abc':
      console.log('User sent /abc command');
      break;
    case 'def':
    case 'ghi':
      console.log('User sent /def or /ghi command');
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Sorry, ${cmd} is not a command.`);
  }
}
```